# Rails not directing to show page after user submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, associations

Working with nested routes and associations.  I have a partial which creates a tenant, but after the creation it stays with the form rendered and the url changes to /tenants.  Desired behavior is that it needs to redirect_to the show page.  Routes are as follows:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :landlords

   authenticated :landlord do
     root "properties#index", as: "authenticated_root"
 end
   resources :tenants
   resources :properties do
     resources :units
   end

  root 'static#home'
end
```

So far the properties and units work (and the landlord) Issue is with Tenants.  Originally I had Tenants nested under units, but had issues there as well.  Partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @tenant do |f| %>

<%= f.label "Tenant Name:" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label "Move-in Date:" %>
<%= f.date_field :move_in_date %>

<%= f.label "Back Rent Amount:" %>
$<%= f.text_field :back_rent %>

<%= f.button :Submit %>

<% end %>

<%= link_to "Cancel", root_path %>
```

Tenants Controller looks like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_landlord!
#before_action :set_unit, only: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_tenant, except: [:new, :create]


  def new
    @tenant = Tenant.new
  end

  def create
    @tenant = Tenant.new(tenant_params)
    if @tenant.save
      redirect_to(@tenant)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @tenant.update(tenant_params)
      redirect_to unit_tenant_path(@tenant)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

private

  def set_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end

  def set_unit
    @unit = Unit.find(params[:unit_id])
  end

  def set_tenant
    @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def tenant_params
    params.require(:tenant).permit(:name, :move_in_date, :is_late, :back_rent, :unit_id)
  end
end
```

Models have associations:

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :unit, inverse_of: :tenants
end

class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property, inverse_of: :units
  has_many :tenants, inverse_of: :unit
end
```

Lastly the show#tenants in rake routes is:

```
tenant GET    /tenants/:id(.:format)                     tenants#show
```

I have extensively searched for this topic, but haven't had any success.  Any help is appreciated.  Rails 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route you are showing near the end of your question:

```
tenant GET    /tenants/:id(.:format)                     tenants#show
```

is not the tenants index; it is the individual tenants/show route. You can tell this because it includes `:id`, which means it will show you a specific tenant having that id.

Try running `rake routes` again. The index route should look like this:

```
tenants GET    /tenants(.:format)                     tenants#index
```

If you want to return to the tenants index after creating or updating a Tenant record, then you need to specify that path in your TenantsController. In both the `#create` and `#update` actions, your redirect line (after `if @tenant.save` and `if @tenant.update`, respectively) should read:

```
redirect_to tenants_path
```

That will take you to the TenantsController, #index action.

In the alternative, if you want to return to the individual tenant show page, then instead change both of those redirects in the TenantsController in both the `#create` and `#update` actions to:

```
redirect_to tenant_path(@tenant)
```

That will take you to the TenantsController, #show action for the current @tenant.

Comment: I ended up changing a few things.  I think my main issue was the routing.  I added a shallow nested route, and everything seems to be functioning correctly.  Thanks for your help @moveson